# Telerik RadComboBox Results Not Showing In IE9

Tags: telerik, internet-explorer-9, radcombobox

I'm using a Telerik RadComboBox (rcb) using the .NET 3.5 framework (using the latest assemblies from Telerik) for an older project. The rcb works fine in Firefox 4, Chrome 10, IE7 and IE8, but the search results don't show in IE9. I also have a parallel project using the 4.0 framework and the rcb does work in IE9 with this version.

Does anyone know what the deal is with the rcb's search results not showing in IE9 using the .NET 3.5 framework? I've tried searching the Telerik forums to no avail...

Comment: I've personally found Telerik to be very responsive to questions on their forums.

Comment: The workaround I'm using for now is to use IE9 in IE8 browser mode using the built-in dev tools. I guess I'll have to wait until I switch to the 4.0 framework assembly version.

Comment: Also make sure you use the latest 2011.1.413 release of the Telerik AJAX suite as they announced full IE9 support in Q1 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed using .NET 4 and the latest assemlies from Telerik.